# Endianess of float numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point

I want to convert float numbers from little endian to big endian but am not able to do it . 
I have succesfuly converted endianess of int numbers but can somebody help with float numbers please

Comment: why are you trying to convert endian of floats?

Comment: This is IEEE754-2008 format floats I believe? What did you try?

Comment: A google search will give some information on this.  Try:  "float endianness site:stackoverflow.com" as the search string.

Comment: [SO search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=float+endianness+[c%2B%2B])

Comment: @johnathon my machine is little endian so when i try to write float to file the byte order is changed and thanks everyone i seem to find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <cstring>    // for std::memcpy
#include <algorithm>  // for std::reverse
#include <iterator>   // For C++11 std::begin() and std::end()

// converting from float to bytes for writing out
float f = 10.0;
char c[sizeof f];
std::memcpy(c,&f,sizeof f);
std::reverse(std::begin(c),std::end(c)); // begin() and end() are C++11. For C++98 say std::reverse(c,c + sizeof f);
// ... write c to network, file, whatever ...
```

going the other direction:

```
char c[] = { 41, 36, 42, 59 };
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof c,"");
std::reverse(std::begin(c),std::end(c));
float f;
std::memcpy(&f,c,sizeof f);
```

The representation of floating point values is implementation defined, so the values resulting from this could be different between different implementations. That is, 10.0 byte swapped could be 1.15705e-041, or something else, or it might not be a valid floating point number at all.

However any implementation which uses IEEE 754 (which most do, and which you can check by seeing if `std::numeric_limits<float>.is_iec559` is true), should give you the same results. (`std::numeric_limits` is from `#include <limits>`.)

---

The above code converts a float to bytes, modifies the bytes, and then converts those bytes back to float. If you have some byte values that you want to read as a float then you could set the values of the char array to your bytes and then use `memcpy()` as shown above (by the line after `std::reverse()`) to put those bytes into `f`.

---

Often people will recommend using reinterpret_cast for this sort of thing but I think it's good to avoid casts. People often use them incorrectly and get undefined behavior without realizing it. In this case reinterpret_cast can be used legally, but I still think it's better to avoid it.

Although it does reduce 4 lines to 1...

```
std::reverse(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f),reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f) + sizeof f);
```

And here's an example of why you shouldn't use reinterpret_cast. The following will probably work but may result in undefined behavior. Since it works you probably wouldn't even notice you've done anything wrong, which is one of the least desirable outcomes possible.

```
char c[] = { 41, 36, 42, 59 };
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof c,"");
float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&c[0]);
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit , i could not understand the last line you wrote which says values are implementation defined where limit of float is true ? and secondly is there a way to read 4 bytes 41 36 42 59 and convert it to float number ? bytes to int and long and short is easy but how are bytes converted to float.

Comment: Sorry but can you tell me the libraries to add for above code to work i am using it in c++

Comment: @FaisalFayyaz I've added information on the headers to include. You can also find this information at http://en.cppreference.com

Comment: Putting the reversed bytes back into a float variable is wrong.  An array of bytes is perfect for storing in a file, a network packet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do such things is to use a union.

```
union float_int {
  float m_float;
  int32_t m_int;
};
```

That way you can convert your float in an integer and since you already know how to convert your integer endianess, you're all good.

For a double it goes like this:

```
union double_int {
  double m_float;
  int64_t m_int;
};
```

The int32_t and int64_t are usually available in stdint.h, boost offers such and Qt has its own set of definitions. Just make sure that the size of the integer is exactly equal to the size of the float. On some systems you also have long double defined:

```
union double_int {
  long double m_float;
  int128_t m_int;
};
```

If the int128_t doesn't work, you can use a struct as this:

```
union long_double_int {
  long double m_float;
  struct {
    int32_t m_int_low;
    int32_t m_int_hi;
  };
};
```

Which could make you think that in all cases, instead of using an int, you could use bytes:

```
union float_int {
  float m_float;
  unsigned char m_bytes[4];
};
```

And that's when you discover that you don't need all the usual shifts used when doing such a conversion... because you can also declare:

```
union char_int {
  int m_int;
  unsigned char m_bytes[4];
};
```

Now your code looks very simple:

```
float_int fi;
char_int ci;

fi.m_float = my_float;
ci.m_bytes[0] = fi.m_bytes[3];
ci.m_bytes[1] = fi.m_bytes[2];
ci.m_bytes[2] = fi.m_bytes[1];
ci.m_bytes[3] = fi.m_bytes[0];
// now ci.m_int is the float in the other endian

fwrite(&ci, 1, 4, f);

[...snip...]

fread(&ci, 1, 4, f);

// here ci.m_int is the float in the other endian, so restore:
fi.m_bytes[0] = ci.m_bytes[3];
fi.m_bytes[1] = ci.m_bytes[2];
fi.m_bytes[2] = ci.m_bytes[1];
fi.m_bytes[3] = ci.m_bytes[0];
my_float = fi.m_float;

// now my_float was restored from the file
```

Obviously the endianess is swapped in this example. You probably also need to know whether you indeed need to do such a swap if your program is to be compiled on both LITTLE_ENDIAN and BIG_ENDIAN computers (check against BYTE_ENDIAN.)

Comment: Yes i need to do swapping of float numbers because i am making a character recognizer using hidden markov model and it takes float numbers as input . my machine is little endian so the number gets very big and some errors occur e.g if i write 00 00 00 03 a integer 3 my machine writes it like 03 00 00 00 . Therefore i assumed float numbers would be similar too.

Comment: What I meant in my last statement was that if you compile that same software on a Big Endian and a Small Endian, then you need to swap only on one of those machines. Not both. In Linux you use #include <endian.h> and then use LITTLE_ENDIAN and/or BIG_ENDIAN at compile time (i.e. #if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN). These may need two underscores as in: __LITTLE_ENDIAN.

Comment: I am actually writing and reading file from same machine . I write to a file and then my toolkit which is Hidden Markov Toolkit reads that file . Am i doing write by changing endians while writing into the file. I mean if i change endian of 00 00 00 03 to 03 00 00 00 and write it to a file . when my toolkit reads the same file will it read it as 00 00 00 03 or 03 00 00 00 ?

Comment: Assuming that you write bytes to your file, and read that back as bytes, then the order will not change. 03 00 00 00 would remain just like that. I'll do a little update to my code to show fread/fwrite calls (although for C++ people say iostream is better...)

Comment: Ben, you mean that my code did not work on some of your computers? Did you try it?